# Tableau Online slow performance

Tags: performance, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have a Redshift database with an insane quantity of data, we use a live connection and tableau_online. The problem is that the load times are really high, almost five minutes. What can I try to improve this?

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot provide solutions for such a general question. You might receive better suggestions if you concentrate on a specific performance aspect, such as improving the performance of a specific query or examining concurrency through Workload Management (eg whether the system is simply running too many queries simultaneously).

Comment: In a similar situation myself with a different DB, you have to choose between live data and slow performance, or an extract with improved performance. Option C would to to subset your data and connect to a smaller version, if this is an option.

Comment: This either needs to be a redshift question or a tableau one. you need to find whether it is redshift that is taking 5 minutes to run the query. or whether it is taking 5 minutes within tableau. then we can focus on fixing the right thing. If it is a redshift issue then you need to provide all the details you can such as table sizes, the query sql etc. How big is insane?

Comment: well its data that is growing per minute, when I check redshift using sql its fast, so I guess its tableau, besides in tableau desktop its a little faster

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of factors that impact performance. I would start with workbook optimization. [Workbook Performance Tips](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/1/5-tips-make-your-dashboards-more-performant-48574)

Comment: hi I already applied some of these tips, the prob is that there are reports that were built some time ago , what can i do i those cases?

Comment: Are they using older versions of Tableau? If so, since you don't maintain Online versioning, I would rebuild them with the latest version of Tableau, 10.5 or 2018.1 as of right now.

Comment: I update desktop every time that its possible/available, I used to think that the reports on tableau online get updated automatically every time that a new version is available? because if not it gonna be heavy rebuild each report and upload it to tableau online again every time that is a new version.

Comment: Tableau Online is upgraded to allow for the latest version of desktop without any intervention on your part. I am just suggesting that as new versions come out, many workbooks benefit from a complete rebuild. Though it is time consuming, if you have a 5 minute wait for a workbook, the product is providing little to no value anyway.

Comment: let me see if i understand ok, if a report was build and upload in ex: tableau desktop 10.0   and now tableau online is 10.5 that could be part of the prob?

Comment: Lets say that you built a workbook in 10.0 and included a workaround for a feature that is now standard in 10.5. you'll have an opportunity for efficiency gains by using the built in 10.5 feature. In these types of cases you would want to do a rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in a similar situation myself, although with a different DB, basically you have to make a choice between a **live** connection to your DB, which, as you've seen, can suffer performance issues if you have a lot of data, or an **extract**.

Tableau want you to use extracts because this where they can really help you improve performance of the workbook over large data sets, but I have been in situations where there is a requirement for live data and Tableau's extracts schedules did not suit my needs.

If you have no options but to use a live connection then consider whether you could partition your data and connect the workbook to a part of it to improve performance, or possibly pre-aggregate some of the historical data to make it more manageable.

May also be worth thinking about whether you need the whole dashboard to connect to live data, or if you could feed live data via a smaller query to a couple of workbooks and have the rest feed off extracted data.

As I'm sure you can see, there is no one-stop solution, it depends what works best for you and the users of your reports.